# Split binary number into multiple digits in excel

Tags: excel

I have a decimal number and I can convert it into binary using DEC2BIN(cell value) function in excel.
Right now it gives the binary value in a single cell, instead, I want each digit in the binary number into multiple cells.

```
Data:

  A          |B         |C       |D       | E      --- Excel Columns
1|21
2|DEC2BIN(A1)
3|
4|
```

Current result:
    Data:

```
  A          |B         |C       |D       | E      --- Excel Columns
1|21
2|10101
3|
4|
```

Desired Result:
    Data:

```
  A          |B         |C       |D       | E      --- Excel Columns
1|21
2|1          0          1        0        1
3|
4|
```

Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: `Data -> text to columns` with a fixed width of `1`. You will need to convert the result of the formula to a value first

Comment: That would break the value of A1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In A2:

```
=MID(DEC2BIN($A$1),COLUMN(A1),1)
```

Then copy it across. You can drag it across in excess of what you need. This will prepare it for use in case you are going to have larger numbers. That way, you will not have to constantly update the code.

[image]

Alternatively, if you are planning on using this code for multiple binary entries, you could put the number in column A then copy the following down as far as you need:

```
=IF(ISBLANK($A1),"",MID(DEC2BIN($A1),COLUMN(A1),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, if there isn't a new answer without dragging it, I shall accept this as the answer.

Comment: @SuryaTej there will not be another way without vba.  If you do not have the dynamic array formula in Office 365 Excel, you will need to use this formula and drag.

Answer (score 1):

If one has the Dynamic Array formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(MID(DEC2BIN(A1),SEQUENCE(LEN(DEC2BIN(A1))),1))
```

in A2 and Excel will spill the result across.

[image]

Comment: My EXCEL 2013 doesn't have the SEQUENCE function, it throws Name error when I use this.

Comment: Then use the other answer.